# How to call Java nio Files.find without the FOLLOW_LINKS Option?

Tags: java, enums, nio

In this example line, Files.find is called with the FOLLOW_LINKS option.

```
Stream<Path> paths = Files.find(
    Paths.get(basePath), 0, eval, FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS);
```

Documentation is written to lead one to believe that FOLLOW_LINKS is optional.

> If the options parameter contains the FOLLOW_LINKS option then symbolic links are followed. 
>   [reference...Java SE 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walk-java.nio.file.Path-int-java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...-)

Passing null for this parameter produces a NullPointerException in Java's FileTreeIterator, which is clearly written to require a non-null value.

```
Stream<Path> paths = Files.find(
    Paths.get(basePath), 0, eval, null);
```

FileVisitOption has only one Enum Constant: FOLLOW_LINKS.

So, is FOLLOW_LINKS really an *option* after all?

How do I call Files.find without this "option'?

What am i missing?

Comment: Try passing an empty list as the last parameter.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I hoped someone would make me say Doh! Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The final parameter is a [*varargs*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html) array. If you don't want to specify any options, leave it out entirely:

```
Files.find(Paths.get(basePath), 0, eval)
```

Comment: I missed that. Perfect. Thanks. Tired I guess.